# aligning the table row in HTML

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I can't find a way to fix the table row height,
if the username exceeded it overlaps to the other column.
check the last two row
[image: check the last two row]

and it's also scrollable at side and the username is still in their position.
[image]

code for single row:

```
<tr>
    <td class="headcol">
        <div class="innerHead">
    <div class="user-id" style="display:none;">18993</div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="user_select[]">
    <a href="/accounts/edit_profile/TestingalksdjaskldjsalkdjalskdjaksduqwoieuoqweuowqeiTesting@gmail.com/18993">TestingalksdjaskldjsalkdjalskdjaksduqwoieuoqweuowqeiTesting@gmail.com</a>      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="forcedWidthUserCode">Tested091237871</td>
    <td class="textAlignCenter">Field staff</td>
    <td class="forcedWidth">Testing</td>
    <td class="forcedWidth">Tested</td>

            <td> N/A </td>

    <td class="textAlignCenter">Active</td>
    <td> N/A </td>
    <td class="forcedWidth"> N/A </td>
    <td> N/A </td>
    <!--<td>N/A</td>-->
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.headcol {
    position: absolute;
    width: 18em;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 0;
}

table tr td {
    /* background: #fff; */
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

how can I align and wrap the text base on the width of the username column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because there is a white space between those nodes (the checkbox and the text node). The line breaks at white space.

There are two way to handle this.

As mentioned by @Supraja Ganji: Use `word-break`.

```
table tr td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

or prevent the whole line from breaking, and hide anything that overflows:

```
table tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: update typo mistake: it should be: white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 1):

Your username is too long and doesnot contain any space, so it is not wrapping.

for td give word-break: break-all

```
table tr td {
    /* background: #fff; */
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a div inside td is a very bad idea.

Using a div instide a td is not worse than any other way of using tables for layout. (Some people never use tables for layout though, and I happen to be one of them.)

If you use a div in a td you will however get in a situation where it might be hard to predict how the elements will be sized. The default for a div is to determine its width from its parent, and the default for a table cell is to determine its size depending on the size of its content.

The rules for how a div should be sized is well defined in the standards, but the rules for how a td should be sized is not as well defined, so different browsers use slightly different algorithms.

Let me know if you require any further help

Answer (score 0):

```css
   

.headcol {
    position: relative;
    width: 18em;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 0;
}
.innerHead {
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody><tr>
    <td class="headcol">
        <div class="innerHead">
    <div class="user-id" style="display:none;">18993</div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="user_select[]">
    <a href="/accounts/edit_profile/TestingalksdjaskldjsalkdjalskdjaksduqwoieuoqweuowqeiTesting@gmail.com/18993">TestingalksdjaskldjsalkdjalskdjaksduqwoieuoqweuowqeiTesting@gmail.com</a>      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="forcedWidthUserCode">Tested091237871</td>
    <td class="textAlignCenter">Field staff</td>
    <td class="forcedWidth">Testing</td>
    <td class="forcedWidth">Tested</td>

            <td> N/A </td>

    <td class="textAlignCenter">Active</td>
    <td> N/A </td>
    <td class="forcedWidth"> N/A </td>
    <td> N/A </td>
    <!--<td>N/A</td>-->
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```